# Android Studio: Manifest merging failed for adding aar for sherlock action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I tried adding sherlock as an aar using gradle and it states an error saying "manifest merging failed. See console for more info".

Where exactly is the console ? I am using Windows, I see no windows in Android Studio claiming to be a console. I presume I would get to see more info here ?

This is my gradle file, my minsdk and tarjetsdk are the same in my manifest and my build.gradle.

Anyone had this and fixed it ?

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0','com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: to show console use command line `gradle(w) assemble -info`(but do not expect something useful) ... i'm pretty sure that actionbar is build with targetSdkVersion 18 and thats why you have this error ...

Comment: Thanks selvin, gradle assemble, so i was checking the docs and i don't fully understand what it is is doing, it says its assemble the jars....   Does recompile ? or check some logs ?  p.s. it does work of course, i can see the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess targetSDK is higher in ABS.
Check console out and set your targetSDK to 18.